# Pandas Groupby python

Tags: python, pandas, file, group-by, dataset

I have a dataset with the names of the countries and some other information such as salary in the file. The problem is that I need to find mean salaries of employees in the file grouped by country_id and city in ranges (0, 5000] (5000, 10000] and (10000, 15000].
I was using this method but the resultant table is not as what I want. Can you help me with that?

```
df = file.groupby(['country_id',"city"])['salary'].mean().reset_index(name="mean") 
bins = [0, 5000]
df['binned'] = pd.cut(df['mean'], bins)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if your range of the salary bin is always 5000, you can create the bin number of each row by using `/` operator and `math.ceil`

```py
import math
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'salary':[
        1231, 5000, 7304, 10000, 12302, 15000,
        1001, 4900, 6012, 9123, 11231, 14923
    ],
    'country': [
        'USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA',
        'UK','UK','UK','UK','UK','UK'
    ]
})
df['salary_bin_number'] = (df['salary'] / 5000).apply(lambda x: math.ceil(x))
df.head()
```

| salary | country | salary_bin_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1231 | USA | 1 |
| 5000 | USA | 1 |
| 7304 | USA | 2 |
| 10000 | USA | 2 |
| 12302 | USA | 3 |

With the `salary_bin_number`, you can create the column name of bin by using below code

```py
df['salary_range_str'] = df['salary_bin_number'].apply(
    lambda bin_number: f'({(bin_number-1) * 5000}-{(bin_number) * 5000}]'
)
```

Then group by `salary_range_str` and `country` to calculate the average salary in each `country,salary_range_str`.

```
df = df.groupby(['country', 'salary_range_str'])['salary'].mean().reset_index()
```

Finally, pivot the column `salary_range_str` to columns.

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='country', columns='salary_range_str', values='salary')
```

Output

| country | (0-5000] | (10000-15000] | (5000-10000] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | 2950.5 | 13077 | 7567.5 |
| USA | 3115.5 | 13651 | 8652 |

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want the answer to have 3 different columns. The column "0-5000" for the mean value of the salary in range 0-5000 in each country, and the column "5000-1000" as the previous one and so on. Is your method helpful for that?

Comment: may you provide an example of your desired output ?

Comment: I think I understand your needs, please wait a minute, I will update my solution.

Comment: I have updated my solution, please kindly check if my solution is what your want or not. :)